# Creating table with latitude and longitude with LeafLet, ASP.NET and SQLite?

Tags: leaflet, sqlite, asp.net

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude and create a table from it, and show in a map, using Leaflet, however I didn't find anything that could help me in my project, the files that I have made are the following:

*class Local* for the Location

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace maps.Models

{
    public class Local
    {
        //[Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set;}
        public double longitude { get; set;}


        //observe that 

    }
}
```

And for the table I use:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace maps.Models

{
    public class TestDbcontext : DbContext
    {   
        public DbSet<Local> Locals { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=C:\Users\joaov\Downloads\local.db");

    }
}
```

I just could implement the following:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var seekPlace = L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
```

But it's far from what I want, which is, given latitude and longitude (Back-end), to put a marker on the map, and to show the saved data in a table.

Comment: GIS SE is a site for focused Q&A, it is not a discussion forum. Your question includes several questions, so please limit it to only one question, you can ask other questions later.

Comment: I just want to know how to get latitude and longitude using leaflet, from a user and displaying in a map.

Comment: Then [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/436722/edit) the question and formulate it like this.

Comment: I agree this question is a bit broad, but am willing to help in chat or some less restrictive conversation

Comment: I would like to know something quite simple in the area, I am surprised that no one knows the answer to it.